# Is there a good beginner's book for array microphone beamforming?

Tags: beamforming

I have been working in the acoustics field for a while, and recently I got myself into Matlab and Python for signal analysis and some signal processing.

After making some test and analysis tools with programming, I got interested in microphone array beamforming.

Simple time-domain delay and sum beamformer were intuitive and easy to try out. But as soon as I got into frost's beamformer and Global Sidelobe Canceller, I can visualize the process, but I have no idea where to start to make this using Matlab or python. I have already tried the built-in Matlab functions for various beamformers, but I want to try to make the beamformer's myself so that I fully understand the process and have more freedom.

I was able to find some books like [Microphone Arrays](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540419532), and it seems like a very good book. But after a couple of equations, I'm very lost. Especially the coherence matrix part, which I know is the key in array processing.

Is there any good book that I can refer to for my level of knowledge? Or is it a prerequisite to know all the mathematical concepts even before I start any of the beamforming work?

It would be really great if there's any beginner's book that explains every process step by step.

Comment: Hi, Do you get and knowledge and want to share?